# C# making an event wait

Tags: c#, event-handling

I'm working on some event-driven code. In one of the components of my system an event sometimes comes up that I have no handler for at the moment. Is there any way to make the event "wait" until a handler is available for it?

Thanks,

PM

Comment: Do you still have to implement the event? Or is it assigned the handler later? If its assigned the handler later, why don't you try assigning the handler before the call?

Comment: sorry, let me re-explain: event E happens. I have only 1 class C that can handle E, but at that moment there is no active instance of the class, so when E is raised it sees no subscribers and nothing happens. Is there a way to make E be handled as soon as an instance of C is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There's no built-in mechanism in C# for queuing events and dispatching them as handlers are attached.** Events are raised synchronously when some interesting activity happens ... "waiting" for a handler would require the process to block.

**You could implement your own event queuing by providing a [custom implementation of the event member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx) in your class.** You would need a separate data structure to cache information about previously "raised" events and queue them for when a handler attaches.

The trouble with the scheme above, is that while it is possible it is highly unusual and a bit confusing. Most developers don't expect events to be raised in such a manner. It is also complicated by the fact that if a large number of events occur without an attached handler you could end up using a significant amount of memory to store events that will never be dispatched. Personally, I would generally advise avoiding such a design.